# Bootstrap full width Navbar two different backround colours on side

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm using standard full width fluid bootstrap navbar from examples in centered inside of the container. What I'm trying to achieve is, I would like to have white background on the left side under logo as well and from logo to right with blue background color. Is it possible? [hope this image will explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvyEK.jpg) Thanks.

Comment: Please show us some code!

Comment: Here is very similar [project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036570/two-colored-navigation-bar/41025579) so I'd like to know if it's possible to wrap it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one way of doing that its tricky but it works

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-header{
    background:#e7e7e7;;
  position:relative;
}

.navbar-header:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e7e7e7;;
    top: 0;
    left: -9999px;
    right: 100%;
}
.navbar-default{
    background:blue;
}
```

[**See demo1**](http://www.bootply.com/iNpxDZ4FLU)

and if you want to skew the edge

[**See demo2**](http://www.bootply.com/E72EdQbbAj)

Comment: That's awesome! This is what I needed. Thanks. Is it possible to apply gradient and skew the side? like here https://jsfiddle.net/yfzxunqg/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use as background-color a "sharp" gradient with only two colors
(use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
I copy here the standard navbar example from the bootstrap documentation:

```css
.navbar{
background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(255,255,255) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 20%, rgb(125,185,232) 20%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 20%,rgb(125,185,232) 20%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 20%,rgb(125,185,232) 20%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: That could work! https://jsfiddle.net/yfzxunqg/ But is it safe? What is the best way to be sure that "bevel" is always next to the logo?

Comment: Safe...well, this system will not work on internet explorer 9 and lower: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient will always do a linear gradient between the two colors, so IMO you should remove the gradient for this browsers.
About your other question, the best thing you can do is 
1) calculate the position of the "bevel" so that it will not interfere with the logo
2) if this is not possible for smaller screen sizes, use media queries and adjust the position accordingly.

The other solution I could suggest is to use a background image to obtain the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a linear gradient like this:

`style="background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);"`

With additional code we might be able to help you more.